# Como concatenar uma string e um valor inteiro em javascript?

Tags: javascript, string

Bom, eu possuo 15 linhas semelhantes em meu código e a unica coisa que muda é o `id` dos elementos que terminam em um número inteiro crescente e diferente dos demais...

Eu tentei substituir essas linhas usando um *loop*, mas sempre que tento rodar o código nada acontece. Usei o `console.log` e a variável está normal. Mas mesmo assim print uma mensagem de erro dizendo que *o estilo nao pode ser setado em um elemento null*: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null`

`

```
    <script>
    function showSeason(obj) {

        /*document.getElementById('episodes_temp1').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('episodes_temp2').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('episodes_temp3').style.display="none";
        document.getElementById('episodes_temp4').style.display="none";*/

        for(i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
            document.getElementById('episodes_temp' + i).style.display="none";
        }


        //essa parte eu tbm queria por em um loop, mas nao tenho ideia de como fazer
        //como serao diversos itens criar 50 cases nao seria uma boa escolha :(
        switch (obj.id) {
          case 'temporada_1':
          document.getElementById('episodes_temp1').style.display="block";
          break
          case 'temporada_2':
          document.getElementById('episodes_temp2').style.display="block";
          break
          case 'temporada_3':
          document.getElementById('episodes_temp3').style.display="block";
          break
          case 'temporada_4':
          document.getElementById('episodes_temp4').style.display="block";
          break
        }
    }

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <?php

        echo "<p></p>";
        for($i = 1; $i < 5; $i++) {
            echo "<button type='button' id='temporada_$i' onclick='showSeason(this)'> Temporada $i </button>";
        }                           

        for($x = 1; $x < 5; $x++) {
            echo "<div id='episodes_temp$x' style='display:none;'>";
                for($i = 1; $i < 50; $i++) { //50 é um valor de teste, pretendo puxar do banco da dados;
                    echo "item $i";
                }   
            echo "</div>";
        }                                                       

    ?>
</body>
```

`
penso que eu poderia tbm substituir o swith por:

`for(i = 1; i < 5; i++) {
    if("temporada_" + i == obj.id) {
         document.getElementById('episodes_temp' + i).style.display="block";
         break;
    }
}`

Comment: Isso acontece porque de fato você não tem no DOM qualquer elemento com ids `'divAba' + i`, pode ter certeza, reveja isso. Também, seria adequado postar a parte do seu HTML, afinal não podemos adivinhar o restante do seu código.

Comment: @felipsmartins, na verdade a o `getElementById` é uma função, que recebe como argumento uma `string`, e no momento da concatenação, o argumento é retornado com o ` i `, sem problemas. Como pode ver nesse exemplo:  https://jsfiddle.net/SamirChaves/xcxj3skp/ . Creio que o problema é o restante do código.

Comment: @SamirBraga Eu entendi o que ele está tentando fazer. E é justamente por isso que a questão dele está faltando detalhes. A mensagem de erro `Cannot read property` é justamente pelo fato de `getElementById` retorna null por não achar no DOM um elemento com o ID que se está buscando. - À propósito, também sou de Fortaleza.

Comment: Primeira pessoa aqui das redondezas que vejo por aqui... rsrs... Pois é, concordo, a espera de novos detalhes Naine...

Comment: @Naine, onde está esse script? Ele pode estar sendo carregado antes do elemento em questão. Tente colocá-lo ao final de seu documento, assim ele será carregado depois que todos os elementos foram rederizados.

Comment: eu editei o post e coloquei o link do codigo que estou usando
usei o pastebin pq achei que ficou muito grande para por aqui :(

http://pastebin.com/bB26SDEK

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pelo que vi em seu código, o problema está na estruturação:

Seu script possui uma função que, pelo menos ao que você mostrou, é declarada, mas não é chamada. Possíveis soluções:

Adicionar a função ao atributo `onload` do `body`:

```
 <body onload="mostrar_abas(obj)" >
```

Usar o método `window.onload`

```
window.onload = mostrar_abas;
```

ou

```
window.onload = function(){
    //conteúdo da função aqui
}
```

Ou ainda deslocar a tag `script` do seu `head` e pô-la ao final do `body`, assim ele será carregado depois que todos os elementos foram renderizados.

Como sua função tem como argumento um objeto, você fará a mesma coisa porém especificando-o;

No seu caso você possui elemtnos que são criados dinamicamento, sou seja, seja o tempo de sua rederização no DOM será diferente dos outros, inclusive do carregamento de scripts. O que lhe recomendo:

Retirar a chamado da função do atributo `onclick` e usar JQuery, assim:

### Modo mais simples COM JQUERY - Update

Adicione uma `class` a todos os buttons que tem um `id='temporada_$i'` como, por exemplo, `class="temporadas"`, e adicione uma `class` a todas `divs` com `id` de *episodes* como, por exemplo, `class="episodes"`. Isso será bem simples, já que você está usando o *loop*. Assim, seu código pode se resumir a isso:

```
$(document).on('click', '.temporadas', function() {
  $('.episodes').hide(); //Esconde todos as div de episódios
  var idNum = $(this).attr('id').match(/[0-9]+$/);// captura o número do botão que foi clicado
  $('#episodes_temp'+idNum).show(); //mostra somente o  div de episódios correspondente ao botão
})
```

Na função acima o evento é passado ao documento e o elemnto em questão é específicado só após por conta que estessão criados dinamicamente.

Comment: http://pastebin.com/BEBsG3Kx é mais ou menos isso.

Peço desculpas se o meu código estiver fora dos padroes eu realmente nao sei como estou indo, é a minha primeira tentativa em fazer um site, me jogaram esse desafio e eu entrei nessa semana passada, sem saber nada de programação web -'

Comment: @Naine, não tem que pedir desculpa, a tentativa é o que nos leva a aprender ;). Imagino que agora saiba qual o problema, vou dar mais uma olhada e lhe aviso...

Comment: @Naine Você linkou o jquery? Caso não, basta adicionar ao seu `head`: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Executando a mesma função via console (F12) ocorre o esperado? Copie e cole no console e clique em tal botão.

Comment: @Naine Olhe aqui: http://pastebin.com/jktwFaL6